# Proper way of creating master and LAYOUT page programmatically

Tags: custom-masterpage, deploy

I am currently porting enterprise site on Portal Solution using Share Point.
MasterPage is deployed succesfully.
Then i create Application Pages, setting in PreInit event handler this recenly deployed Master.
All works fine, until custom layout page is gonna be created.
What i do:
Going to site settings -> Look and Feel -> Designer -> Page Layouts-> Create new page layout.
After it i get an error. Share Point log viewer shows this stacktrace:

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/CreateNewHtml.aspx, Error=Value can not be undefined.  Parameter name: g   in System.Guid..ctor(String g)     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design.DesignUtilities.GetHtmlMasterPages(SPWeb web)     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Design.DesignUtilities.GetMasterPagesDataList(SPSite site, Boolean useAspNetMasterPageUrl)     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreateNewHtmlPage.LoadValues()     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreateNewHtmlPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     в System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     in System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Obviously, `GetHtmlMasterPages` method calls `new Guid("guidstring")`and pass for some reason `null` value inside.

What i  tried:

- Set Master Page for the whole SPWeb object. (`SPWEb.MasterUrl`), cause of previously i did it only for Application Pages what was being tested. But, exception is still alive.
- Adding attribute `DoGUIDFixUp="TRUE"' to File element in deploying module,   but it did not help.

Well, for some reason integrity is broken and Share Point doesn't track my Master Page properly (i guess).
Any ideas?
Any step-by-step guidelines from those, who already made similar things is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by reactivation publishing feature.